# Plot.ly API throws randomly JSON decoding error while creating graph

Tags: python, json, graph, plotly

I have following problem with Python 2.7 and Plot.ly API and I am not sure whats going on and where is the problem. Before I write to authors I am going to try to ask here. I have a script that scans a specific websites, their links and analyzes content (words, counts, etc). The result is plotted by Plotly as a bar graph. Everything works fine, script is run every 30 minutes. But what happens every day few times is, that the method that handles data upload through API, like `response = py.plot([data])`, says `"ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"` (`data` is not empty, counting works fine). What I don't understand is that:

1) It was working with the same script code few minutes ago

2) It doesn't matter what data I put inside the variable `data` (like simple numbers for x and y)

3) After the above mentioned error, the data are sent and published, but the descriptors - layouts (axis setup, title, size of graph) are not because they are set in the next step separately and script is terminated at the position of creating response (well I could merge that together, but the error still appears and I'd like to know why)

4) when I create empty .py file with basic example like:

```
import plotly
py = plotly.plotly(username='someUname', key='someApiKey')
x0 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
y0 = [20, 14, 23];
data = {'x': x0, 'y': y0,'type': 'bar'}
response = py.plot([data])
url = response['url']
filename = response['filename']
```

Then the result is the same, no JSON object could be decoded, to be exact.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\plotly-0.4-py2.7.egg\plotly\plotly.py", line 69, in plot
    r = self.__makecall(args, un, key, origin, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\plotly-0.4-py2.7.egg\plotly\plotly.py", line 142, in __makecall
    r = json.loads(r.text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Data are published but I am not able to set layouts. At the time when the word counting script works fine, this small piece of example code works as well.

Does anyone have the same experience? Well I am not a coding pro, but it seems that the problem could be somewhere outside of my code. Or, maybe I missed something, anyway I am not able to debug/understand the reason.

Thank you for tips

Answer (score 1):

Chris here, from Plotly. Thanks for reporting the issue. You definitely aren't doing anything wrong on your end! This error arises because of some transmission issue from plotly to your desktop. The API expects a string in JSON format from the plotly server but received something different. I'll look into it further. Definitely email me if it happens again! --chris[at]plot.ly

Comment: Hey Chris, considering your answer could potentially be here for a while, you might want to provide more information on the proper venue for submitting bug reports.